# Replacing words with conditions

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would need to check if a row contains a number (n), a blank space and a word in the list (house, houses, casa, case), in order to replace it with

- `10.00` if the number is equal to `1`;
- `10.00*n` where `n` is a number not equal to `1`.

Example:

```
H_C
4 case        
9 apart          
1 house
```

Expected output

```
H_C              New_H_C
4 case          40.00  
9 apart          9 apart
1 house          10.00
```

I have tried using a mix of `re.search` looking at the list (house, houses,case,casa), and `strip` for adding `.00`, but I am confused on how to use it to determine the conditions `10.00` and `10.00*n`.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Why the second row `9 apart` doesn't change?

Comment: Should 4 case turn into 4 apart in the output?  That doesn't seem to be in your logic

Comment: sorry it was my fault. The first word was `case` in the expected output!

Comment: You haven't answered @Quang's question. Also, where did `"New_H_C"` come from? I am downvoting the question but will reverse it if you clarify the question by editing.

Comment: I am not understanding your question. 9 apart is the value of that row. It does not change as it is not included in the list. New_H_C is a new column where I save the values after updating the values. I cannot understand why you downvote a question that has already received a good answer (which means that some users correctly understood my question). I am sorry if sometimes I might be unclear, but English is not my first language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this regex:

```
words = ['house', 'houses', 'casa', 'case']

# extract the relevant numbers
s = df.H_C.str.extract(f'(\d+) ({"|".join(words)})')[0].astype(float)
# multiply with 20

# you can search for `format` string function
df['New_H_C'] = np.where(s.notna(),s.apply(lambda x:'{:.02f}'.format(x)), 
                         df['H_C'])
```

Output:

```
       H_C  New_H_C
0   4 case     4.00
1  9 apart  9 apart
2  1 house     1.00
```

Comment: Thank you @Quang Hoang. How could I get .00 at the end? I would need this format

Comment: @LucaDiMauro see updated. Remember that now you have all strings in `New_H_C`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciated it

Comment: Sorry Quang Hoang, I have been trying to understand your code. and I would like to ask you something on your code (I am a new learner of Python). In case I had to replace `1 house` with `20`, `4 case` with `20*n`, what part should I have modified?

Comment: I have tried your code and it works well. However all the values that do not need to be changes are `nan`. Do you know why? Please let me know if you prefer I opened a new keyboard. Thank a lot for all you r help.

Comment: @LucaDiMauro sorry, it was me that missed those cases. See update.